# What is difference between tab content realization?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

There is my approach to show the tab content:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The First Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

What is difference between this

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template *ngIf="condition">
      The First Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and this?

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <app-component *ngIf="condition"></app-component>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A:**

```
<app-component *ngIf="condition"></app-component>
```

If `condition` value is truthy, then the above code loads the `app-component`.

**B:**

```
  <ng-template *ngIf="condition">
      The First Content
  </ng-template>
```

The above code wouldn't render anything. This is because `<ng-template>` is a template element and is never displayed directly. It only works when used with structural directives.

Before rendering, Angular replaces the above code with:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition">
  <ng-template>
    The First Content
  </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

This is why even if `condition` value is truthy, no content would be displayed. `<ng-template>` would be replaced by diagnostic comments by Angular, and since there are no structural directives, no content would be displayed.

Comment: My question more about Tabs, what about `matTabContent`? Now I have bugs when each tab has component inside content, it switches tabs randomly

Comment: @OPV - As of now, I answered the question you have asked, you didn't mention anything about `matTabContent` and the error you are facing. You have to edit your question and state the problem correctly, preferably with a reproducible example on StackBlitz or other sites.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach1:**

```
<ng-template *ngIf="condition">
      The First Content
</ng-template>
```

Above template will not be rendered in view since  it's virtual element. We can use it with template reference variable & *ngTemplateOutlet directive like below:

```
<ng-template #myContent>This is ngTemplate content</ng-template>
<div *ngTemplateOutlet="myContent"></div>
```

In the above code myContent is a template reference variable with '#' symbol. So  element will get replaced with  content. By using this, we can define reusable template and use in many places.

**Approach2:**

```
<app-component *ngIf="condition"></app-component>
```

if Condition is truthy, it will render app-component template.